# How to make a continuous animation movement of an image in jquery on window load function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have seen this [site](http://www.logartis.info/site2011/.) today

Actually it is built in flash.
But I want to move either the tree in the said flash in jQuery fixing it in a fixed position in my page or the birds moving around the browser in jquery.
Can it be done?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#banner li:first-child').nextAll('li').hide();   
    /*  $('#banner li:gt(0)').hide();*/
        setInterval(function(){
        $('#banner li:first-child').fadeOut(3000).next('li').fadeIn(3000).end().appendTo('#banner');
        }, 3000);
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    ul#banner {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        background:#fff;
        position:absolute;
        top:97px;
        left:185px;
    }
    ul#banner li {
        list-style:none;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background:#fff;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width:980px;
        height:451px;
    }
    ul#banner li h1 {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left:435px;
        font-weight:normal;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .relative {
        position:relative;
    }

    </style>
<body>
    <ul id="banner">
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><img src="pic2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
              <h1>Willkommen...</h1>
              <img src="pic3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li>
              <h1>Willkommen...</h1>
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li>
              <h1>...in einer neuen Sphare!</h1>
              <img src="pic6.jpg" alt="" /></li>
          </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: I cannot get it Mohana what shall be the html can you show me a demo? Oh! Sorry there is the html. You are giving here three pics are these for the tree movement ?

Comment: No No Mohana that I haven't asked for . Anyway thanks for it. I have just want to move the tree as it is in the flash.